# read: A specified flag is not valid for this command

Tags: bash, ifs

I'm getting this error in a HP-UX machine

```
    + IFS=; 
    /home/machine1/folder/borrado_de_logs.sh[45]: read: A specified flag is not valid for this command.
```

And I'm using this code

```
    head -1 $rutatemporal/logfechas.log > $rutatemporal/cabecera.txt
    cabecera=`cat $rutatemporal/cabecera.txt`
    IFS=';' read -a arreglo<<EOF
    $cabecera
    EOF
```

In Hp-UX its seems that `read -a` is not allowed
what argument I should use with `read`?

the content of cabecera.txt is this:

```
2019-02-01;/home/user/deletelogs/somelog.log
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably because [`-a` is not a POSIX compliant flag](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html) support for the read command. So it is not surprising that the default shell available in your HP-UX machine is *not* supporting it.

You can still use the `read` command without `-a` to split and store on individual variable names as below. Also you don't need a here-doc to read from the input file, but rather use the `read` command directly on the file itself

```
IFS=\; read -r date path < "$rutatemporal"/cabecera.txt
echo "$date"
echo "$path"
```

Answer (score 0):

Type

```
$ help read
```

and you can see the available options and their meaning.